# Effect of square integrable Chern curvature on underlying bundle

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $\left(E,h\right)$ be a hermitian holomorphic vector bundle over a complex manifold $M$. Then there exists a unique hermitian connection $\nabla^h$, the $\left(0,1\right)$-part of which is the holomoprhic structure of $E$.

If one assumes that the curvature of $\nabla^h$ is square integrable then a number of interesting theorems can be proven. Such as extending the bundle $E$ across an analytic subset $A$ as reflexive sheaves, when $M= N\setminus A$ (e.g. discussed by [V. Shevchishin](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242975608_The_Thullen_type_extension_theorem_for_holomorphic_vector_bundles_withL_2-bounds_on_curvature)).

The reason that integrability allows such results is clearly of an analytic nature, since mostly the integrability is used to solve certian PDEs.

My rather vague question is: Can integrable Chern Curvature be described in more Algebro-Geometric terms?

Clearly it implies a non zero amount about the underlying bundle and the extension results suggest some type of "triviality" towards "infinity" (e.g. assume $N$ is a compactification of $M$).

Essentially I am interested in results that reformulate the integrablity condition into other terms or implications of integrable curvature.